# Symfony 3 doctrine error of namespace with AbstractCollectionPersiste

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I get this error when inserting with doctrine on my server:

> Attempted to load interface "CollectionPersister" from namespace "Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

The folder:
vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection

AbstractCollectionPersister:

```
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork;

/**
 * Base class for all collection persisters.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 * @author Roman Borschel <roman@code-factory.org>
 */
abstract class AbstractCollectionPersister implements CollectionPersister
```

CollectionPersister:

```
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Collection;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;

/**
 * Collection persister interface
 * Define the behavior that should be implemented by all collection persisters.
 *
 * @author Fabio B. Silva <fabio.bat.silva@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.5
 */
interface CollectionPersister
```

Composer:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
```

It's working on local but not on the server. I've tried to add the use but it doesn't recognise it, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

On local, changed the composer.json:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.5",
```

Run composer update, and copy the doctrine vendor to the server = problem solved.

Comment: No need to add "solved" to the title - we don't do that here. Just accept this answer as correct (using the tick mark to the left) when the system lets you.

Comment: I just saw that I just need to wait 5 more hours.
Thank you for the tip.